# UIWebView blank white page when rotated or simulated in iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uiwebview

1. My problem is: When i run my UIWebView, it only works correctly when simulated in iPhone (any model), and when i rotate the view to landscape or change the devices, it only shows a blank white page.
2. After i look for some answers in StackOverflow (still cannot get a fit solution): I wonder why certain apps layout in Xcode can be rotated properly or even resized according to the size of devices, just by using constraint (e.g.CardGames), but some (e.g.UIWebView) must have a code inside for the apps to be resizable or rotatable?

Update Question:

1. I just realise that the blank pages only appear on iPad simulator (both landscape and portrait), iPhone 6 Plus and iPhone 6s Plus (landscape view only)
2. This is my code:

   ```
   import UIKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController{

   @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
   @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   let url=NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")
   let request=NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

   self.webView.loadRequest(request)

   searchBar.text="http://"
   }

   func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchbar: UISearchBar) {

   searchbar.resignFirstResponder()

   let text=searchBar.text
   let url=NSURL(string:text!)
   let request=NSURLRequest(URL:url!)

   self.webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
   }
   ```

Really appreciate your answer :)

Comment: It's impossible to give to you a correct answer about your issue, there are too many possible answers, please add some of your code..

Comment: Hi men, i updated my question already, u can view the code there. Thanks in advance!